# DynamoDB UpdateItem Doesn't Work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is pretty much straight out of the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html), but like most things AWS, it just doesn't work and isn't documented well at all.

The following fails with `"The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update"`

```
var messageId = "f244ed33-d678-4763-8f46-0f06514d5139"
var sequenceId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var lastActivityThreshold = now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

var response = client.UpdateItem(new UpdateItemRequest
{
    TableName = "TheTable",
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> { { "SequenceId", new AttributeValue { S = sequenceId } } },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {":MessageId", new AttributeValue {S = messageId}},
        {":Now", new AttributeValue {N = now.Ticks.ToString()}},
        {":LastActivityThreshold", new AttributeValue {N = lastActivityThreshold.Ticks.ToString() }},
    },
    UpdateExpression = "REMOVE Messages[0] SET LastActivity = :Now",
    ConditionExpression = "Messages[0] <> :MessageId AND (LastActivity <= :LastActivityThreshold OR attribute_not_exists(LastActivity))",
    ReturnValues = ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW
});
```

This is the document I'm trying to update (as seen in JSON view in the AWS Management Console):

```
{
  "LastActivity": {
    "N": "635753575712635873"
  },
  "Messages": {
    "SS": [         
      "f244ed33-d678-4763-8f46-0f06514d5139",
      "f668d2a5-3a4a-4564-8384-5b5a51c9bad3"
    ]
  },
  "SequenceId": {
    "S": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
}
```

I've tried many variations of the code above, striaght down to removing all `ExpressionAttributeValues` and the `ConditionExpression` and just using `REMOVE Messages[0]`, but it doesn't work and throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply a document path to a non JSON item.  There's no concept of ordering in a set, so if you want to remove the first item, you'll need to load it into memory and iterate over it.  In short, you'll need to use a list in this case.